# Failing to include using Entity Framework and LINQ

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the latest forum threads in my forum, just like this:

```
var threads = _context.Threads.Include(x => x.User).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).Take(3).ToList();
```

However, this gives me the following exception:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Before I load these threads, I am loading some settings, like this:

```
var frontPageSettings = _context.Settings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == Constants.SettingsKeys.FrontPageSettings.ToString());
```

Could this be the issue?

I have absolutely no idea what is happening, or how to get around it. Any guidance towards a solution is highly appreciated.

If you need more information such as stack trace, please let me know.

**EXTRA INFO**
I'm using Entity Framework for MariaDB (MySQL) and ASP.NET Core

**EDIT**
If I remove my `.Include(x => x.User)`, the exception disappears, so I believe this has something to do with the include

Comment: Are you sure you don't use some `Async` method w/o `await`-ing it? Or access the same `DbContext` instance from multiple threads?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm injecting my `DbContext` into the controller and using that instance. It is not an async action

Comment: That's the problem mate, with these member variables and injections, one never knows what happens. If you do `var threads = new YourDbContext().Threads.Include(x => x.User).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).Take(3).ToList();` you will not get such error.

Comment: @IvanStoev But I can load the threads just fine, except for when I include my user?

Comment: Currently there is always a possibility to hit EF Core (or EF Core data provider) bug. Try the snippet from my previous comment, if it works, then the problem is somewhere in your code. If it doesn't, then it's a bug and you can post it on their issue tracker.